# Angular How to create a dynamic expansion checkbox list and how to capture value for API?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, checkboxlist

I have an design of dynamic checkbox list under expansion header, as it is dynamic so how can I get all the checkbox value dynamically and send to API?

P.S. How to loop from API to display such dynamic list? I very new to Angular and Tyepscript so I need some help.
[image]

Below is the response from API, how do I group them based on categoryID?

```
{
"code": "200",
"message": "Success",
"data": [
    {
        "categoryId": "ADMDSHB",
        "accessId": "ADPRATE",
        "catAccessStatus": "A",
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-09T09:22:16.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-09T09:22:16.000Z",
        "BoRefCategory": {
            "categoryId": "ADMDSHB",
            "categoryDesc": "Dashboard-admin"
        },
        "BoRefAccess": {
            "accessId": "ADPRATE",
            "accessDesc": "Adoption Rate"
        }
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "ADMDSHB",
        "accessId": "AGTMLR",
        "catAccessStatus": "A",
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-09T09:22:33.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-09T09:22:33.000Z",
        "BoRefCategory": {
            "categoryId": "ADMDSHB",
            "categoryDesc": "Dashboard-admin"
        },
        "BoRefAccess": {
            "accessId": "AGTMLR",
            "accessDesc": "Agent MLR"
        }
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "ADMDSHB",
        "accessId": "AGTMLR",
        "catAccessStatus": "A",
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-04-09T12:07:44.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-09T12:07:44.000Z",
        "BoRefCategory": {
            "categoryId": "ADMDSHB",
            "categoryDesc": "Dashboard-admin"
        },
        "BoRefAccess": {
            "accessId": "AGTMLR",
            "accessDesc": "Agent MLR"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can assign your checboxes to an array of objects with name and value like this in your ts file:

```
 selectedBoxes = [    {
  name: "Adoption Rate",
  status: true
},
{
  name: "Agent MLR",
  status: false
},
{
  name: "Agent Test",
  status: false
}]
onRefresh(){
  console.log(this.selectedBoxes);
}
```

And then in your html :

```
<div *ngFor="let box of selectedBoxes">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="box.status" value="test" (ngModelChange)="onRefresh()"> 
{{box.name}} </div>
```

Now when you check a value you can see the changes made in onRefresh function.

///
Update to get the from api with the sample response:

```
  selectedBoxes = [ ];

  ngOnInit() {
  for( let i in this.response.data){
   this.selectedBoxes.push({name: this.response.data[i].BoRefAccess.accessDesc, status: false})
  }
  }
```

Comment: but how to handle when the checkboxlist is dynamic and can grow to many more?

Comment: You can push them to an array with name and value as you get the response from api within a for loop.

Comment: also one more question, you see the all checkboxes under same category...but on the JSON response they are in 3 different objects, how to loop through them and group them together?

Comment: please give a sample json response in order to help you